# Celery beat не запускается

Tags: python, fastapi, celery

Имеется проект, в котором использую  Celery beat планировщик.
Код:

```
    from celery.schedules import crontab
    app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'run-every-midnight': {
        'task': 'celery_tasks.app.collect_expiring_user_ids',
        # 'schedule': crontab('59,23,0,0,0')
        'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=20)

    },
}
```

Передаю в ключ 'schedule' через cronab аргументы hour и minute , как и описано в документации и во многих других инструкция. В этом случае при запуске beat через команду, получаю зависший лог в консоли:

[2023-12-03 00:19:25,093: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...

При варианте ключа 'shedule', который закомментирован, все запускается корректно. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: а вы читайте документацию. параметры hour и minute должны быть строковыми, а не числовыми.

Comment: В документации, говорится, что можно передавать значения именно в таком формате (int), поэтому и я не понимаю, что не работает.